# How to get numbers from string

Tags: php, preg-match

I am currently developing a script using `imap` to get emails and insert it onto mysql. basically a ticketing system.. The script works great and inserts data into MySQL but I am having some issues to update a current ticket. I would like to grab the ticket number from the email subject and update that ticket. below is what I have so far. any suggestions?

The subject looks like this: `RE:Ticket#12345 - Testing Ticket creation`. What I need to do is to get the numbers between `#` and `-`, match it against the database and update. Currently, it is just inserting new items into MySQL.

```
/* try to connect to the mailbox*/
    $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect: ' . imap_last_error());
}elseif($eml_service_control =="0"){
    echo 'Email to Tickets Service has been disabled by the system Administrator';
}

/* If all goes well then let us grab the emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */ 
    rsort($emails);

    foreach($emails as $email_number){
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
        $seen=$overview[0]->seen;
        $date=$overview[0]->date;
        $date2=$overview[0]->udate;
        $from_email=imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist($overview[0] 
->from, 'localhost');$from_email=$from_email[0];
        $from_email=clean($from_email->mailbox."@".$from_email->host);
        $subject=clean($overview[0]->subject);
        $subject1=$overview[0]->subject;
        $preg=preg_match("/Ticket#ID - ([0-9]+\s)/b", $subject1, $res);
        $wo_id=extract_numbers($overview[0]->subject);print_r($res);
        $wo_id=$wo_id[0];
        $wo_id=$res[1];
        if(!$wo_id){ $wo_id="";}
        $message=strip_tags($message,"<br><div><p>");
        $message=clean("Received <b>$date</b><br/><hr/>$message");
        $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_customer` WHERE
CUSTOMER_EMAIL='$from_email'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($q)==1){ $customer_id=mysql_fetch_array($q); 
$customer_id=$customer_id['CUSTOMER_ID']; } else { $customer_id=""; }
            print_r($overview);
            $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE TICKET_ID='$ticket_id'") or die(mysql_error());
            $n=mysql_num_rows($q);
            $date2=date("H:i:s", $date2);
            $priority="1";
            if($n==0){
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tickets` 
                    (SCOPE, DESCRIPTION, PRIORITY_ID, CREATED_TIME, OPEN_DATE, STATUS, CUSTOMER_ID)
                    VALUES
                    ('$subject', '$message','$priority', '$date2', '$date', '0', '$customer_id')");
            } elseif($n==1) {
                mysql_query("UPDATE tickets SET DESCRIPTION = CONCAT
('Received <b>$date</b><br/><hr/>$message <hr/><hr/>', DESCRIPTION) WHERE 
TICKET_ID='$ticket_id'") or die(mysql_error());
            }
            $status = imap_setflag_full($inbox, $email_number, "\\Seen \\Flagged", ST_UID);
            imap_delete($inbox, $email_number);
        }
        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo "<!-- debug -->"; 
    }

    /* close the connection */
    imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: How do the email subjects get generated?

Comment: In the future, it would be better if you only post the minimum block of code to replicate the isolated issue.  Future SO readers will have to scan your whole code to find your preg_match line.  I was tempted to cut your question right back, but then your follow up question (comment to George) would no longer make sense.  What was that `\b` pattern modifier doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("/Ticket#([0-9]+)/", $subject, $output);
$output[1];
```

Would return the number from any string that contains `Ticket#{{number}}`.

Comment: Perfect! this works. i just replace preg_match("/Ticket#([0-9]+)/", only. I guess I was stripping too many. Thanks

Comment: i would also like to limit the number of emails to insert each time i run the script. any suggestions?

Comment: @user3620142 `$i = {{limit}};` above your `foreach` statement. Then the first line inside it `if ($i-- === 0) break;`. You should move your MYSQL inserts outside the foreach and do them at the end so you only call the database once.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
// Grab the ticket_id from the subject line ($str) 
preg_match('/Ticket#([0-9]+)\s+?/', $str, $matches);
$ticket_id = $matches[1];

// Check if ticket id exists
$result=mysql_query("select count(*) as total from tickets where ticket_id ='$ticket_id'");

$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ( $data['total'] > 0 ) {
    // Do mysql update  
} 
else {
    // Do mysql insert
}
```

Comment: Hi ricky, Thank you. this works too but George solution is much easier. I also now realize what I was doing wrong. stripping too many.